# Non-Abelian Chern-Simons Theory References

Tags: resource-recommendations, lie-algebra, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, wilson-loop

I am studying Chern-Simons theories and am fairly familiar with the usual Abelian $U(1)$ Chern-Simons theory. I am now looking to extend my knowledge to non-Abelian Chern-Simons and am having a hard time finding quality references, lecture notes, that discuss the quantisation of the level $k$, the Wilson lines, etc for this case. Does anyone know of some useful sources to consult?